# Чтение почтовых сообщений

Tags: java, email, selenium

Мне хотелось бы «зайти» в почту, найти письмо, содержащее определенное словосочетание в заголовке, и считать из него ссылку (для тестирования регистрации).

Как это можно сделать?

Comment: свой код есть? или полность за Вас надо написать? Примерный алгоритм - стартовать браузер, перейти к почте, залогиниться, найти письмо, нажать, достать ссылку.

Comment: если просто зайти в почту через браузер это я могу, интересует использование javax.mail

Comment: Зачем тогда тут тег selenium?

Comment: потому что я все по ходу тестов в селениуме делаю

Comment: Т.е. ты знаешь как сделать через селениум, теперь ты хочешь узнать, как сделать через javax.mail ?

Answer (score 2):

Этого кода будет достаточно для вашей задачи.

```
package test;

import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.search.SearchTerm;
import java.util.Properties;

public class JavaMailTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
        try {
            Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
            Store store = session.getStore();
            store.connect("imap.mail.ru", "<your_mail>", "<your_password>"); // put your imap-server, user and password here
            Folder folder = store.getFolder("INBOX");   // or your folder
            folder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
            Message[] messages = folder.search(new SearchTerm() {
                @Override
                public boolean match(Message msg) {
                    // put your condition here
                    return false;
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception mex) {
            mex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```